# Is "steering document" a word in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

In my native language we call an organisation's policy documents *styrdokument*, which translates literally as *steering documents*. *Steering documents* is also the word used by many organisations (including my own) in translations into English. Now I'm wondering whether this really works in English – *steering document* is not listed in any of the dictionaries that I've checked (Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, Longman), and when I google it it basically only appears in texts written in a non-English context.

So: can *steering documents* be used as a synonym for *policy documents*, or am I right in thinking that this is simply translationese, and that the better choice would be *policy documents*, for documents detailing an organisation's rules and regulations?

Comment: Policy isn't quite the same as rules and regulations, which usually have more detail. "Policy documents" is fine if it is what you mean.

Comment: @Peter Oh, ok – so what would you call the different documents detailing rules and regulations then? And also: would you say "steering documents" works? Thanks for you help!

Comment: I would use the word "regulations" both for the rules themselves and for the document containing them. Perhaps "a copy of the regulations". "Steering documents" sounds awkward - "guiding documents" would be a bit better. "Governing documents" may be what you need.

Comment: @Peter Yes – "governing documents" is probably the exact equivalent! Thank you!

Comment: A ***steering document*** isn't a very common term, but it's more or less the same thing as a ***white paper*** - a document written early in the planning process, outlining the most important aspects of a project.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for excellent help as always! So "steering document" is, in fact, not just unidiomatic, but outright **wrong** in this context?!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you have a source for this? Not that I doubt that you're right (I know you are!), but because it's good to have a "proper" source to fall back on when I bring this up with my superior.

Comment: It's not a common usage, so it's not easy to find a "definition" (you'd certainly never find the collocation **steering document** in any dictionary). But you'll find many online definitions for ***a steering committee***, where "steering" has more or less the same meaning. And in some cases, the primary purpose of the steering committee is simply to produce a steering document anyway.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "the organization's rules and regulations", but one version of this is often called an **employee handbook**, which specifically lists the rules and regulations that individual employees must abide by.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks! I think the exact phrase I'm looking for is actually "governing documents" :)

Comment: Note that ***at the time when it's written***, a "steering document" always defines ***future*** constraints and intentions. It doesn't make sense to write a steering document describing the ***current*** situation. This is very different to a *[staff] **handbook***, which is almost always written "after the fact", to summarise all rules, procedures, etc., that have already been implemented.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can not use steering document as a synonym for policy document in English.

Steering document makes no sense in English, though it might make sense in Norwegian or Swedish, but we can't always translate our own language's words directly into English.

If you want to know more about synonyms to policy document, [have a look here](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/policy_document)

Comment: Of course it "makes sense"! Anyway, it's in [Hansard](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22publish+a+steering+document%22) (official record of proceedings in the UK parliament) - *Before Easter we will **publish a steering document** which will inform and guide this and launch the stakeholder engagement process*. Presumably the speaker there had some specific reason for not using the more common term ***white paper***, implying that the two terms aren't *quite* synonymous in every context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think texasboy probably meant that it's translationese, rather than that it doesn't make any sense. Either way the answer as a whole is good and well intended, so I hope whoever downvoted it will upvote it again :)

Comment: Tack Texasboy! Det är exakt så här jag tänker också :) It makes sense to us, when we just translate it back to Norwegian/Swedish, but speakers of English won't understand it as meaning what we think it means.

Comment: I downvoted this answer! It's not some kind of erroneous literal translation from another language - the usage exists independently in English (cf ***steering committee***, which is in widespread use). So although this answer might have been posted in good faith, it's still ***wrong**!*

Comment: ... but I would just point out that "steering documents" are much more common in ***software development & planning*** than in other business contexts.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. I have heard this before, and @FumbleFingers pointed out where -- software development.